# Revealing a tableView on button press - iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I'm trying to reveal a `UITableView` if you click a certain button on my `UIViewController`.

I thought I could simply write:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    table.hidden=YES;
}

-(IBAction)task:(id)sender{

    table.hidden = NO;
}
```

That doesn't seem to work. I've added the tableView to a Xib and connected it. Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint and ensured the action is being called and the table is not nil?

Comment: does it get hidden in the first place?

Comment: No Sorry should have mentioned it appears when the view loads

Comment: you have added the IBOutlet and datasource and delegate?

Comment: I have in my header file  UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate> Do I need to set delegate in .m?

Comment: i'm not sure that it's a point but it's better to use self.table...

Comment: @AndreaF yes. you need to do so. set it to self.

Comment: Andrea F: As Kevin pointed out above, you need to set a breakpoint at the `table.hidden = NO;` line of code, and when you tap the button, make sure that: 1. The breakpoint is hit; and 2. the value of table is not nil. Once the execution stops, go into the console and type `po table` and press return, and you should see if table is nil. I would guess that the task action never runs (because it is not hooked up to the button action correctly, make sure to link to touch up inside), or that table is nil (because it is not linked correctly to an IBOutlet).

Answer (score 1):

If you're creating the tableView in a XIB file then set the hidden property there. When your view loads from the XIB file I believe those settings take precedence (and default setting in XIB is hidden = NO).  So select the tableView in your XIB file and set the hidden property (it's a checkbox).  Then remove the `table.hidden = YES` line in your `viewDidLoad` and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks! it's hidden now. Problem is getting it unhidden.

Comment: You mean `table.hidden = NO` isn't working? Can you confirm that the outlet is connected properly from your XIB file to your .h file?